# BizTalk: terminate messages

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

If I need to build a specialized web app to be able to terminate messages processed by specific send ports, WMI is one option.  Are there others? and are there pros/cons to each approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to terminate messages programmatically by referencing the Microsoft.BizTalk.Operations.dll assembly. That will allow you to use the [`TerminateInstance` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.operations.biztalkoperations.terminateinstance%28v=bts.10%29) of the BizTalkOperations Class, which allows you to reference a remote BizTalk instance (using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee822140%28v=bts.10%29) constructor) without enabling remote WMI administrative access.

You may also need to reference Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline.dll in Visual Studio to get IntelliSense to work.

The BizTalk SDK includes a sample app that you can review, as well, to see how to look up a message instance, which you'll need for the parameter to the TerminateInstance method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg163868

For example:

```
BizTalkOperations _operations = new BizTalkOperations()
IEnumerable messages = _operations.GetMessages();
foreach (BizTalkMessage msg in messages)
…
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the "/null" Send Port Adapter?  This allows you to send messages to a "null" port, where they effectively disappear.  Source code can be found [here](http://biztalk.eliasen.dk/Adapters.aspx), although it hasn't been updated since BizTalk 2006 R2.
If this isn't relevant to what you are trying to achieve, maybe some additional information regarding the use case would help.

Comment: Not specific to the issue at hand, but I think we'll be making use of this information in other areas.  Thanks.